# Recursion on a global vector variable in R

Tags: r, variables, recursion, global

I have created a vector:

```
code_vector <- vector(mode="character", length=8)
```

and my intention is to modify this vector recursively (following Shannon-Fano's algorithm to create variable length codes).

I have two functions. The user calls "shannon_fano" and then "shannon_fano" calls "shannon_fano_rec" to build the code inside vector "code_vector".

```
 shannon_fano <-function(prob_S, D){
    code_vector <- vector(mode="character", length=8)
    shannon_fano_rec(...,code_vector,...)
    print(code_vector) #3
 }
 shannon_fano_rec <-function(prob_S,D,code_vector,i,j){
     #shannon_fano_rec calls itself several times
 }
```

When I finally print "code_vector" after the function shannon_fano_rec has ended, code_vector is empty. So it's clear that code_vector is not functioning as a global variable here.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" stylistically, writing a function that modifies a global variable. You should `return()` the result, and pass in any needed arguments.

Comment: R is a functional language so it tries to minimize side effects (you shouldn't change values of variables outside your immediate scope). Also, functions are lexically scoped so they see variables from environments where they were created, not where they were called. It would help if you filled in your example a bit more with a clear desired output to offer more precise guidance, You probably should add the vector as a parameter to your recursive function and return an updated value. `code_vector <-shannon_fano_rec(...,code_vector,...)`